# Multiple Link Attribute Styles in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextview

I'm trying to come up with ways to achieve different styles for different types of links in the same `UITextView` using `NSAttributedString`.

I need a text view that can handle standard web links (i.e. `http://example.com`) the way standard data detectors do. But I also want to use some custom links (custom scheme, which would be handled as links internal to the app), which would have different colours.

`UITextView` only allows one type of styling using `linkTextAttributes`. I've tried setting the colour attributes on the custom links, but they get overridden by the data detector process (which unfortunately doesn't offer any hooks to customize).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe set `textView.dataDetectorTypes` to nil to prevent the data detector process?

Comment: Thanks for the thought. Unfortunately the data detectors are useful (to avoid having to roll my own URL detection, it's user content for plain links), and doing so doesn't avoid the `linkTextAttributes` overriding the other styling.

Comment: This [link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/113/nsattributedstring-by-example) goes into details you're looking for.  `NSMutableAttributedString` has an `addAtribute` method that allows you to an apply an attribute to a range of the string.

Comment: Thanks @DPrice. The issue is that `linkTextAttributes` overrides any attributes I've set using an attributed string. I'm looking for a way around that.